# Get path of execution - from where I start jar file

Tags: java

Can I in my Java app find current path where I start that jar file ?
Path of execution ( example: `C:\test\test_one> java -jar test.jar` to get `C:\test\test_one` ) ?

Comment: Such techniques will not work in applets or apps. launched using JWS.  Oracle's view is that code has no business knowing where the Jars are installed.  Do not be surprised if this bad strategy to achieve an unstated goal breaks in the near future, and when you complain to Oracle, they shrug and reply 'security fix'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can. Within your code you can call System.getProperty("user.dir") to return the working directory of the application.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that this is exactly what was asked for - the the path were you were when you started the jar file. Also known as current working directory. Do NOT confuse with the location of the jar file!